# Utilizar o Chromium no firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, chromium

Me indicaram o componente chromium CEF4Delphi e em testes vi que ele funciona muito bem no VCL mas no firemonkey (FMX) ele não funciona.

Eu gostaria de saber se é possível, utilizando o componente chromium DCEF3, fazer igual o já citado CEF4delphi que me permite pegar os valores dos inputs existentes em meu arquivo HTML utilizando o DOMVisitor, pois até agora não consegui. E se for possível, como posso fazer?

Utilizo o Delphi RAD Studio 10.2 Tokyo com a linguagem Pascal

Estou utilizando o firemonkey (FMX)

Comment: Você precisa olhar na documentação do componente se ele é VCL e FMX.

Comment: @JúniorMoreira o DCEF3 ele é tanto para VCL e FMX já o CEF4Delphi é apenas VCL e é por isso que quero utilizar o DCEF3 só que nele ainda não consegui acessar o DOMVisitor.